# Regex to remove words with more than 2 digits

Tags: php, regex

I've got a list of product names with codes with 3 or more digits and some letters in it. Example: **XZ11A8**, **G123T5M** and **194FF4**. Now I want to remove these kind of words with a regex. As a beginner in regex I came up with this:

```
preg_replace('/\d{3}+/', '', 'Product X XZ11A8');
```

Unfortunately this only works when the three digits are right next to each other. What is the right regex to always remove a word with 3 or more digits?

Comment: `$s = preg_replace('/\b(?:[A-Za-z_]*[0-9]){3}\w*\b/', '', $s);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern might work for you:

```
/\b([A-Z]*\d[A-Z]*){3,}\b/i
```

Test implemented in Python:

```
import re

pattern = r'\b([A-Z]*\d[A-Z]*){3,}\b'

string1 = 'Product X XZ11A8'
string2 = 'Example: XZ11A8, G123T5M and 194FF4.'

print(re.sub(pattern, '', string1, flags=re.IGNORECASE))

print(re.sub(pattern, '', string2, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Product X 
Example: ,  and .
```

The assumption here is that what you want to remove is always alphanumeric (or underscore) and *nothing* else.  E.g. if characters like hyphens get involved, then `\b` might fail us in this situation.

Comment: note this regex might get slow if there are a lot of words like `12dfafasfasgiugiugigigu` due to double-backtracking

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
\b(?=(?:\w*\d){3,})(\w+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dR1rJ1/3)

---

As noted in comments, `\b(?:[a-zA-Z_]*\d){3}\w*` is an optimized version. Use that...

Comment: note `\w*\d` needs to backtrack, so a possessive variation `\b(?=(?:[a-zA-Z_]*+\d){3})(\w+)` might perform faster in case an optimization was be needed... or even `\b(?:[a-zA-Z_]*+\d){3}\w*`

Comment: in Python when using `re` and not [pcre](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pcre) - the best without possessives would be `\b(?:[a-zA-Z_]*\d){3}\w*`

Comment: @Aprillion: Excellent optimization. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
\b([a-zA-Z]*[0-9]){2,}[a-zA-Z]*\b
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$n = 'Product X XZ11A8';
if (strlen(preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $n)) >= 3) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

I replace all non-numeric chars and check the length of the remaining string.